# How do I safely power a triphase motor and an electric hoist with a triphase AC alternator?

Tags: power-electronics, alternator

The alternator has 12 kW, 21.7 amps and 400 V. For the motor we have 3/3.3 kW, 11.7/6.8 amps then 220/380 V and 250/440 V. The electric hoist we have 900 W and 220-240 V.

Comment: What frequency does the alternator put out? What frequency does the motor expect? I guess it is likely to be 50 Hz? Is the electric hoist tri-phase also, or single phase?

Comment: The electric hoist is single phase. The frequency put out by the alternator is 50 Hz

Answer (score 1):

The alternator can drive the motor if it's configured in star (wye) for 380 V.

The hoist will need a transformer unless it can be reconfigured to switch from delta to star.

Comment: If the hoist is single phase, the motor can possibly act as a rotary convertor for it - if you can run it unloaded whenever you are using the hoist. (You would run the hoist from one phase and the motor's neutral)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can I configure the alternator for 380 V ?

Comment: Adjust the voltage regulator if it has one.